# Find the CDF of a distribution with "recursive relation"

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Let's imagine a scenario that 10 people draw money from a money pool containing $M_0$ dollars:

Let $X_n$ be the remaining money in the pool after the $n$-th draw ($X \in [0, M_0]$, $0$-th draw means no draw has occurred), and uniform random variable $K \sim \mathcal{U}(0, 1)$.

Here let's define method to generate the value of the $i$-th draw:

$$ M_i = \max(0.01, K \frac{X_i}{n_c(i)}), i=1,2,3,\dots, 10 $$

where $n_c(i)$ is the current number of players who haven't drawn, so $n_c(i) = 10 - i + 1 = 11 - i$.

**Question: I want to find out the CDF of the $n$-th draw $M_n$: $F_{M_n}(m)$**

Here's my attempt:

When $m > 0.01$,
\begin{align*}
F_{M_n}(m) &= P\left[ \frac{XK}{n_c(n)} \le m \right] \\
&= P\left[ XK \le m n_c(n) \right] \\
& = \int_{0}^{M_0}\int_{0}^{\frac{mn_c(n)}{x}}f_{XK}(x,k) dk dx \\
& = \int_{0}^{M_0}\int_{0}^{\frac{mn_c(n)}{x}}f_K(k)f_X(x) dk dx \\
& = \int_{0}^{M_0}\int_{0}^{\frac{mn_c(n)}{x}}k f_X(x) dk dx \\
\end{align*}

The problem is, to get the expression of $f_X(x)$, we need to know the expression of $F_{M_n}(m)$, and vice versa. It's like a recursive relation:

$X_i = M_0 - \sum_i M_i$ where $M_i$ is the $i$-th draw.

Since each draw is dependent on each other, I cannot use Central Limit Theorem for this, no to mention that there is only 10 draws.

How do I solve this? What method can I use?

**Edit thx to @ben:**
The mechanism of drawing money is like this:

- the min value of a draw is $0.01$ dollar
- the value is determined by multiplying a random factor (in $[0,1]$) $K$ with the remaining money, divided by the remaining players.

Comment: Perhaps I've missed something, but I'm afraid the first paragrah leading up to the formula for $M_n$ does not make sense to me.  What is $K$ supposed to represent?  Where does this formula come from?  If $n=1$ and $K>\tfrac{1}{2}$ then you get more money than you started with.  None of that makes any sense to me.

Comment: @Ben I was going to ask the same thing. In addition shouldn't $X$ be indexed by $n$, i.e. really $X_n$ as you have defined it.

Comment: Even with the recent edits you fall into the same problem as @Ben defined. As a simple example, imagine for the last draw $i = 10$, we draw $K = 1$ from the unif. The amount drawn is still $2X_i$ (and another issue I think it should really be some function of $X_{i-1}$).

Comment: Rather than giving us a strange formula for $M_n$, perhaps it would be more fruitful to specify the mechanism by which your $n$ people take money from the pool.  That way we can assist you to specify the correct recusrive equation.

Comment: @DaleC  I think I mistakenly added $2$ to the formula of $M_i$, it should really be $M_i = \max(0.01, K\frac{X_i}{n_c(i)})$. Updated, and thx

Comment: @Ben-ReinstateMonica The mechanism is like this: first the min value of a draw is 0.01 dollar. second, the value is determined by multiplying a random factor (in [0,1]) $K$ with the remaining money, divided by the remaining players.